# Mount LUKS encrypted hard drive at boot

Tags: partitioning, mount, encryption, fstab, luks

I have Xubuntu 14.04 on a SSD device (the *HOME* was encrypted correctly during intallation), additionally I have a HDD with a encrypted partition with extra data which I would like to mount in */mnt/hdd*. For making these I followed the next steps:

(Previously I had encrypted the disk with LUKS following this post http://www.marclewis.com/2011/04/02/luks-encrypted-disks-under-ubuntu-1010/)

**Check the UUID**

```
sudo blkid 
/dev/sda1: UUID="b3024cc1-93d1-439f-80ce-1b1ceeafda1e" TYPE="crypto_LUKS"
```

**Make a keyfile** with the right passphrase and save it in my *HOME* (which is also encrypted).

```
sudo dd if=/dev/urandom of=/home/[USERNAME]/.keyfiles/key_luks bs=1024 count=4
sudo chmod 0400 .keyfiles/key_luks
```

**Add the key**

```
sudo cryptsetup luksAddKey /dev/sda1 /home/zeugor/.keyfiles/key_luks
```

**New entry in /etc/crypttab**

```
hddencrypted UUID=b3024cc1-93d1-439f-80ce-1b1ceeafda1e /home/[USERNAME]/.keyfiles/key_luks luks
```

**Update the initial ramdisk**

```
sudo update-initramfs -u -k all
```

Then, to test it, I used the follow command to start cryptdisks:

```
sudo cryptdisks_start hddencrypted 
 * Starting crypto disk...                                                       
 * hddencrypted (starting)..
 * hddencrypted (started)...
```

To check *hddencrypted* was mapped:

```
ls /dev/mapper/
control  hddencrypted
```

**Create a mount point**

```
mkdir /mnt/hdd
```

**New entry in /etc/fstab**

```
/dev/mapper/hddencrypted /mnt/hdd ext4 defaults 0 2
```

Validate fstab without reboot:

```
sudo mount -a
```

**Mount the encrypted partition on boot**

Now I have mount it in/mnt/hdd as I proposed. But I wold like to make this automatically after reboot. But before I can log in, I get this error:

```
the disk drive for /mnt/hdd is not ready yet or not permit
```

All this makes me think that */etc/crypttab* can't access to the keyfile which is located in my *HOME* (other encrypted partition). I don't know the order which the system follows to unencrypted and mounts the units. My *HOME* should be unencrypted before my HDD for giving access to read the keyfile.

I would appreciate any insight as to why this happens.

**UPDATE:**
If I locate the keyfile in */boot* (no encrypted), instead of in my */home/[USERNAME]* (encrypted) the */dev/sda1* and update the entry in */etc/crypttab* is perfectly mounted on boot time.

Comment: How is `/home/$USER` encrypted? A full disk encryption like LUKS or based of ecryptfs?

Answer (score 12):

A key file in the /boot directory can be read by any other operation system booted on your machine that is able to mount the filesystem on that /boot is located. Thus, encryption is not really effective. This argument applies to all key file locations on unencrypted file systems.

To avoid key files on unencrypted file systems a password can be used for decryption. Create a strong password for the device. Then, change the line in /etc/crypttab to

```
hddencrypted UUID=b3024cc1-93d1-439f-80ce-1b1ceeafda1e none luks
```

and keep the entry in /etc/fstab unmodified. Ubuntu 14.04/16.04/18.04 asks you for the password on startup.

Comment: combining @solt87's answer and this answer would complete this answer.

Comment: It's effective if the boot drive is also encrypted, correct?

Comment: Yes, if the boot drive is also encrypted, it is effective. But then, you need a key/password for your /boot partition. Where to put this key?

Answer (score 7):

Does it work if you replace "defaults" in fstab with

```
rw,suid,dev,exec,auto,user,async,relatime
```

(According to the [mount](https://linux.die.net/man/8/mount) man page, it's the same as "defaults" except for "user".)

Answer (score 1):

Make sure the hddencrypted partition is listed *after* the home partition, in both `/etc/fstab` and `/etc/crypttab`.  As the `crypttab (5)` manpage states:

> The order of records in
>          crypttab is important because the init scripts sequentially iterate through crypttab doing
>          their thing.

Also you could try adding the `noearly` option to the latter partition in `/etc/crypttab`:

```
hddencrypted UUID=<...> /home/[USERNAME]/.keyfiles/key_luks luks,noearly
```

In a normal situation, you could indicate that the home partition must be mounted first by adding it to     `CRYPTDISKS_MOUNT` in `/etc/default/cryptdisks`, but since it is itself encrypted, I have a feeling that would not be a good idea.

Comment: This will not work as ubuntu tries to decrypt all partitions and *then* mount them. Thus the key file will not be available.

Comment: As of 2020 (Ubuntu 19.10) this works (`noearly` wasn't even necessary). I put the keyfile in /etc/luks (the main disk is also LUKS encrypted) .