# ecryptfs - decrypt and mount at boot with USB key

Tags: boot, server, ecryptfs, decryption

I have a system running Ubuntu Server as a testbed for some services that I want to get familiar with. I decided to let the installation procedure set up encryption. I knew all along that I would have to decrypt it with the passphrase in order to get the system booted, but I assumed it wouldn't matter since it will only boot once or twice a month.

However, my brother has informed me that he is a victim of power outages at the residence where this server is located. This means we have to explain to his girlfriend how to turn on the computer, attach a keyboard, connect a monitor (she just can't understand that she can type to the computer without a display, so whatever) and input the passphrase for us, while we are at work.

I have arrived at the conclusion that I should just put together a USB key that can be plugged in before powering on the computer, to avoid all the trouble.

Is this possible with ecryptfs? Is there a tutorial or simple list of instructions available so that I can knock this out and focus back on the stuff I care about?

EDIT: I am aware that this is possible with LUKS and dm-crypt, but unfortunately the magical encryption that Ubuntu hands you during the installation is only ecryptfs so my question is specific to that.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know you cannot do this with ecryptfs, but it should be possible with LUKS.

I don't know how it would work out in your scenario with a headless server and the given circumstances. I think it would result in the key being always plugged in. I'd suggest buying and configuring a UPS and [OOB](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Out-of-band_management) over the USB-key method.

- [Mount LUKS encrypted hard drive at boot](https://askubuntu.com/q/450895/40581)
- [HOWTO: Automatically unlock LUKS encrypted drives with a keyfile](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=837416)
- [Dm-crypt/Device_encryption - Unlock the root partition at boot using a keyfile](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Dm-crypt/Device_encryption#Unlock_the_root_partition_at_boot_using_a_keyfile) (Instructions are specific to Arch Linux)

Comment: Thanks. I'm aware of how to use a keyfile with LUKS and have done so in the past on a personal Arch laptop. If there's no way to use a keyfile with ecryptfs then I'll probably just reinstall without encryption. Simply too much trouble otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

One possibility you might want to consider is getting a [USB Rubber Duckey](https://hakshop.myshopify.com/collections/usb-rubber-ducky) to do the job. It is a flash drive-shaped device that impersonates a keyboard to deliver its payload of key presses, the way you might if you were typing to it without a screen. That way, she can just plug it in the same way she would with a regular flash drive.