# Devices with same model names appearing once in Disks utility

Tags: usb, disk, rename

Two of my external hard disks (/dev/sdb and /dev/sdc) that have the same model and properties are appearing as one in Ubuntu 16.04's Disks utility.They seemed to have been assigned the same ID according to lsusb (152d:0564). Is there a way to rename them so that they appear as separate buttons as I'd like to be able to manage them separately?

```
$ lsusb
Bus 002 Device 004: ID 152d:0564 JMicron Technology Corp
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 152d:0564 JMicron Technology Corp

 $ sudo lsblk -o NAME,FSTYPE,MODEL
NAME                                        FSTYPE      MODEL
sdb                                         crypto_LUKS /W RAID5
└─luks-9442fad3-fddc-372a-af82-6d4d15cc1198 ext4
sdc                                                     /W RAID5
```

`/dev/sdb` and `/dev/sdc` in the same Disks window:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Edit I:

Okay, after reading your comment I realized, that i missed something. **The problem you have seems to be a bug in gnome-disk-utility itself.** Check  https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=887979 and https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=709065
I guess these two describe the same bug that you encounter.

My explanation below is not a fix. It is a workaround in case your Partitions/Volumes will not be mounted automatically. Unfortunately my workaround does not work with luks encrypted volumes. I never used luks yet.
From what i have read, it is possible to mount them manually or *more or less* automatic by fstab. The problem is that for an automatic solution you will need to save your passphrase on your machine: [Mount LUKS encrypted hard drive at boot](https://askubuntu.com/questions/450895/mount-luks-encrypted-hard-drive-at-boot). It might also be possible to be prompt to enter the passphrase https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-newbie-8/uuid-in-etc-fstab-for-luks-partition-4175425909/

---

Workaround for automount without luks:

If you type `lsblk --output NAME,SIZE,FSTYPE,UUID` your UUID's, that belong to your partitions should be diffrent. If not, I am surprised.

Here is my Output. sdb is my external drive. It has a Volume sdb1 with an UUID of 3593-DE9E

```
alex@SchlepptopLubu:~$ lsblk --output NAME,SIZE,FSTYPE,UUID
NAME     SIZE FSTYPE UUID
sda    223,6G        
├─sda1    16G ntfs   F81A2CE61A2CA41A
├─sda2    45G ntfs   B09E8A9C9E8A5AAC
├─sda3     1K        
├─sda5     2G swap   c9b7a567-cff5-4967-a73d-7a042e8851af
├─sda6    11G ext4   db850438-e5b3-4540-b99d-64e84d1685a4
└─sda7    30G ext4   8c0ef57b-0a9d-4b7a-a177-ffa7e8295594
sdb      7,2G vfat   3593-DE9E
sr0     1024M
```

Next create folders on your Desktop for each volume that you want to mount.

Next go to `sudo nano /etc/fstab`. Do not delete anything in this file! In case, create a copy of the file as backup before you continue with your modifications.
Inside `fstab` create a new line at the end of the file and write 
`UUID=YOUR_UUID_OF_DRIVE_A /PATH/TO/YOUR/CREATED/FOLDER/FOR/DRIVE_A/ FILE_SYSTEM_TYPE OPTIONS DUMP PASS`

In my example with my UUID and the filesystemtype corresponding to my drive: 
`UUID=3593-DE9E /home/alex/Schreibtisch/drive_A/ msdos defaults 0 2`

Check `man fstab` for filesystem and options. In general i would try `msdos` or `ntfs`. In your case `ext4` might be the right one.

Create as many entries as volumes you want to be mounted.

Comment: Yes sorry, "icons" on the desktop, I will edit my post to show a screenshot of Disks. Unfortunately modifying /etc/fstab didnt work.  Not sure if it's because my devices are luks encrypted.

Comment: I have edit my answer. I didnt realize that you are talking about disk-utility. Does this bug prevent you from accessing your drives or will your drives be mounted automatic without any issues?